# Database design for movie catalog

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, erd

I'm designing a database for an exercise for class and am stuck in the design. In inventory system there are DVD's (divided into 3 Categories: TV, Music Vid, Movie). Within each of those categories it has its own subset of information - TV Category Info: TVInfo1, TVInfo2, TVInfo3 ; Movies Category: MInfo1, MInfo2, MInfo3, MInfo4 ; Music Video Category: MVInfo 1, MVInfo2.

I'm unsure how to incorporate that the Category Type has its own unique attributes dependent on each category. For my tables so far:

```
DVD(Title [PK], CategoryID[FK])

Category(CategoryID[PK], TYPE)

CatMovie(Title [PK,FK], CategoryID[PK,FK], MInfo1, MInfo2, MInfo3, MInfo4)

CatMV(Title [PK,FK], CategoryID[PK,FK],MVInfo 1, MVInfo2)

CatTV(Title [PK,FK], CategoryID[PK,FK],TVInfo1, TVInfo2, TVInfo3)
```

Not sure if that seems right. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Instead of `Title`, you can have a unique `INT AI` id.

Comment: Thanks, can you clarify what the INT AI stands for?

Comment: `INT` with `AUTO_INCREMENT` then make it your reference and title is a separate field with `UNIQUE` defined `INDEX`.

Comment: Wait. I can give you a design sample.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the INT AI. I'm confused on how to handle Categories. Since there are three distinct categories (TV, Music Video, and Movie) and each of those categories has its own unique attribute, I would imagine I would have to create a table that combines the Specific DVD and Category and then the category attributes. But since the category attributes is dependent on the category I'm not sure how to design the table at that point.

Comment: Please wait. I can give you a good design but it'll take time. Please be patient. I can also provide you a reference for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, its just a simple database for a library of films. You can have design like this:

[image]

Now, following your specs, your `title_mstr` table contains all your titles. The `title_category` table will contain your categories(`Movie` or `TV`). Then your info per category would be in `category_info` with reference to the `title_category`. This schema also includes a foreign key for each.

Here's the code:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `title_category`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `title_category` (
  `title_cat_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `title_category_desc` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`title_cat_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `title_mstr`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `title_mstr` (
  `title_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title_cat_id` INT NULL,
  `title_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `title_desc` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `title_details` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`title_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `movie_name_UNIQUE` (`title_name` ASC),
  INDEX `title_cat_id_idx` (`title_cat_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `title_cat_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`title_cat_id`)
    REFERENCES `title_category` (`title_cat_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tape`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tape` (
  `tape_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `tape_category_id` INT NULL,
  `movie_id` INT NULL,
  `tape_details` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tape_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `title_category_info`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `title_category_info` (
  `title_category_info_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title_cat_id` INT NULL,
  `title_category_info` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`title_category_info_id`),
  INDEX `title_cat_id_idx` (`title_cat_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `title_cat_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`title_cat_id`)
    REFERENCES `title_category` (`title_cat_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

For better understanding, you may refer to this link:

- [Database Answers dot com](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/library_of_film_tapes/index.htm)

Comment: Thank you again, very helpful. In the case that if the Category would be "TV" and "TV" has the following attributes: Stars, Episodes, and Creators or if the Category was "Movie" and Movie has the following attributes: Directors, Writers, Stars, Synopsis - how would you link those together? The sub categories have their own unique attributes and that's where I get confused.

Comment: Attributes? wait. You misunderstood. Have you visited the link? Other infos of the title can be in a separate table with a foreign key.

Comment: I think I understand now (just visited the link. Just to confirm my example would be similar to how in the link Tapes have a Tape_Category and them from Tapes, it can split off into a specific category (Rushes or Masters) which in my examples would be TV or Movies. Within that ERD example you gave me I see how Tapes split off to "Rushes" and "Masters" - how would you read that in terms of cardinality? Would it be that Tape has none or one Rushes or Masters?

Comment: Actually that was just an example. If you browse the site, you will have a lot of data models in which you can study and get the idea from:http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/